# How to set ImageView's bounds to it`s subCALayer's frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, calayer

I have an ImageView and I want to add the image(frame to ImageView) through the attaching the CALayer's sublayer to it.

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var setPoster1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var setPoster2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var setPoster3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var setPoster4: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // adding a sublayer with the frame
        let myLayer = CALayer()
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "Main-Poster-Frame")?.imageRotatedByDegrees(3, flip: false).CGImage
        myLayer.contents = myImage
        setPoster1.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)

        // setting superlayer's(ImageView) bounds to myLayer's frame

        myLayer.frame = setPoster1.bounds

        myLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter
```

I'm setting myLayer's frame equal to ImageView outlet's bounds and it doesn't work (image and frame to it don`t match each other).
How could I fix it? :-)

[Poster(ImageView) and frame for it with offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZJaf.png)

Comment: To clarify, you have an ImageView displaying an image, and you want to overlay a second image which is a picture frame?

Comment: Exactly! ImageView(poster inside) + layer(picture of the frame)